# MSIEXEC not installing an MSI setup if /QUIET parameter is used to suppress the UI

Tags: .net, windows-installer, installshield, setup-deployment

I have an MSI installer that was created using Install Shield Limited Edition, I can install it normally by directly running it.

I can also install it using MSIEXEC if I do not use the /QUIET parameter, but if I use the /QUIET parameter, the application does not get installed.

What can be the reason behind it? When I directly run the MSI, it prompts for License Agreement, can this be the reason for it not being installed in silent mode?

Comment: Have you tried running the command from an elevated cmd prompt?

Comment: As the Christopher mentioned most likely the problem is the command prompt is not elevated, so the UAC stops the installation. If you will create a verbose log you should see this in the log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here was something different - after a restart of the system, it got installed silently also without opening the command prompt with elevated permissions.

Answer (score 15):

I had this same issue. I know the original question is answered but I thought I would post here for others searching for the answer like me. To do the silent install you have to have administrator privileges. Run command prompt as administrator and it works.

Answer (score 8):

The solution is to use **/passive /qn** instead of **/quiet**.

**/quiet** = Quiet mode, no user interaction. This means that the default action is taken into consideration when the installer is requesting UAC rights (that is NO)

**/passive** = Unattended mode - progress bar only
so, when you set /qn, that means progress bar with No UI. Pretty much the same thing, but in another way :)

Answer (score 3):

Open MSI file with some editor like Instedit and open InstallUISequence table. You'll see all the actions that are executed during the graphical part of the installation. InstallExecuteSequence table hold all actions executed after you press the install button, or when you do a silent install.

If you find one action that is being executed only in InstallUISequence, try to find if it's making some changes in the system. It's against the best practices, but many msi do it.

Most probable cause is that some property is necessary and obtained in some window, and you need to "inject" it using parameters in command line. See in table Property for properties all caps (this are the ones you can use).

Answer (score 1):

Have you logged your installation?

Typically the license agreement page doesn't prevent install, though you could author it that way.